# Outlook prompt for credentials

Tags: outlook-web-addins

When we use the Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync, Outlook will often prompt for a credential - there appears to be no request on the line at that moment (i.e. not spurred by a 401).  If we cancel, no ill effect occurs.  Our files are served from a web service that is "anonymous", and we pass a one-time-use key on the URL.  I'm not sure why Outlook is prompting at all....

[image: Outlook prompts]

Comment: Can you check whether you also get this auth prompt when using Attach File (see linked answer)? This may be the same issue described in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53657200/7823505

Comment: And is there a public URL you can share that reproduces the issue? We can also investigate to determine the cause of the issue.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how I missed it, but now I'm seeing the 401 in the trace.  It seems related to an issue we were seeing already with 'OPTIONS' (and 'HEAD') command being sent by Outlook, (co-incidentially sent with an empty Bearer token).  This is a known behavior of Outlook as in this article: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vsofficedeveloper/2008/03/11/description-of-the-microsoft-office-existence-discovery-protocol-2/ .  Luckily for us, since we are the ones serving the file, we (hopefully) can adjust our responses so that Outlook does not prompt for credentials.

Comment: Two more links to add to the reading list: https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/899927/you-are-redirected-to-a-logon-page-or-an-error-page-or-you-are-prompte and https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/838028/how-documents-are-opened-from-a-web-site-in-office-2003

Answer (score 0):

In our current configuration we are not seeing any more prompts for authentication.  We respond with 200 OK, no body, on both HEAD and OPTIONS (in the HEAD response we provide the content length of expected response, in the OPTIONS response we provide the content length of 0).  The authentication settings of our IIS web app is anonymous and Windows enabled.  I am running Outlook 2013 and also seeing a lot of PROPFINDs, which IIS is responding with 405 Not Implemented.  This solution won't help if you are using a file service that is outside of your control.